# running android emulator without vtx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, android, emulator

Currently, android's avd manager requires you to enable hardware virtualization from the bios. However, I'd like to avoid this ,so I searched up and I found this post that said you can run the [emulator with ARM images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455756/how-can-i-run-android-emulator-for-intel-x86-atom-without-hardware-acceleration) without hardware virtualization. I also installed required components by:

> sudo apt install bridge-utils cpu-checker libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon qemu qemu-kvm

yet when I `kvm-ok` it shows this:

```
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_amd
INFO: For more detailed results, you should run this as root
HINT:   sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
```

doing `sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok` results in:

```
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_amd
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: KVM (svm) is disabled by your BIOS
HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
      and then hard poweroff/poweron your system
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

`Android studio` itself shows this:

[image]

**Even though its probably a safe thing, I'd like to avoid messing around with the BIOS** as much as possible, so I'm ready to deal with a bit of slow emulation and run the android emulator (that comes with android studio) without virtualization if possible. What options do I have?

EDIT: even though android studio complains kvm not found, the system doesn't seem to come online, either the connection times out after 300s, or the following error is shown: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqIsy.png)

I'm on ubuntu 20.04LTS, with AMD 5950X processor.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been raised in the post
[How can I run Android emulator for Intel x86 Atom without hardware acceleration on Windows 8 for API 21 and 19?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455756/how-can-i-run-android-emulator-for-intel-x86-atom-without-hardware-acceleration)

The following is an extract from the
[answer by Eslam Sameh Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883295/165358):

> In current AVD manager you can't. You just have the opportunity to use
> ARM images which will not need hardware virtualization.
>
> To run ARM images:
>
> 1. Open AVD manager.
> 2. Create a new 'Virtual Device' OR right click an existing image and select 'Duplicate'
> 3. Choose arm* instead of x86/x64.
> 4. Continue with the wizard.
> 5. Run!

The answer notes that this will work, but the emulation will be much
slower than when using virtualization.
If it's too slow to suffer, you might consider turning on
hardware virtualization in the BIOS.

Comment: but, this actually doesn't work using the latest android studio atleast I've tried. The studio still doesn't find /dev/kvm, but I do actually get a blank screen from the virtual device

Comment: With this method you shouldn't need kvm.

Comment: I've edited the update above